# What is the difference between timzeone US/Hawaii, Pacific/Honolulu and HST

Tags: timezone

I was curious about the the following timezone. From their names, it seems they refer to Hawaii, is there any difference between them?

```
US/Hawaii            Hawaii
Pacific/Honolulu     (GMT-10:00) Hawaii Time
HST                  UTC-10:00 Hawaii
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research, their are some timezone ids are following the same rule. So technically, they are the same. Here is a related post to help me out. https://coderanch.com/t/583150/java/timezone-getavailableids-shows-duplicates